# How to hide the Price attribute in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, attributes

I was able to hide the price on the frontend but I am unable to hide the attribute. Under the Attribute set the price attribute is locked. I can hide it with `CSS` but is that the proper way ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You **can't remove** or **delete** the `price` attribute because it is a required one for products, if you want to hide it from your product list attributes in front side, you can set it in : `Admin > Stores > Attributes > Product > select the price attribute > Store Frontend properties > use in product listing > Set to NO`, you have also some other config like use it in catalogsearch, promotion etc...